# Getting outer script to my HTML page without conflicting with CSS attributes

Tags: javascript, html

I want to embed a GitHub *[gist](http://gist.github.com)* into my webpage, and in order to do so I have to include an outer JavaScript script using `<script src>` (as you can see [here](https://github.com/blog/122-embedded-gists)).

Thing is, I'm inserting the outer script inside a `div` element, which has the `max-height` CSS attribute. And with the script inserted in there, the attribute is not respected (there are no height limitations, the script takes as much space as it needs full-size).

Is there a way to apply some kind of fix to it, or does the fact of inserting third-party scripts into my page limit my control over it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the javascript that you are embedding, all it does is write into the page some content and a stylesheet with some classes in it. If you added some of the embedded classes to your own stylesheet you can then modify them to suit your needs. For instance, in order to get the `max-height` attribute into the main content area of the gist you could add it to the `gist-data` class on your local and it will override that class. I've set up an example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/uudjK/1/

Comment: Thank you very much! Hadn't thought about that.